# Using a Shapeless Nat returned from a function as a parameter for another function

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have the following function which takes a list of K-dimensional points of the shape *Point(d0, d1,...,dK)* and returns the index of the dimension at which the range is largest. The Index is returned as a **Nat**:

```
def findMaxRangeDim[T, H <: HList, L <: HList, K<: HList](data: List[T])(
implicit gen: Generic.Aux[T, H],
zipper: Zip.Aux[H::H::HNil, L],
maxMapper: Mapper.Aux[mergeMaxMap.type, L, H],
minMapper: Mapper.Aux[mergeMinMap.type, L, H],
diffMapper: Mapper.Aux[absDiffMap.type, L, H],
indexZipper: ZipWithIndex.Aux[H, K],
folder: LeftFolder.Aux[K, (BigDecimal, Nat), maxIndexFinder.type, 
(BigDecimal, Nat)]
  ): Nat = {/*implementation*/}
```

Let's say that I have another function that takes a data point and a **Nat**, and returns the element located at the dimension denoted by the **Nat**:

```
def getAt[T, H<:HList, N<:Nat](p: T, n: N)(
    implicit gen: Generic.Aux[T, H],
    at: At.Aux[H, N, BigDecimal]
  ) = {/*implementation*/}
```

In can confirm that:

```
// This compiles:
  getAt(data.head, Nat._1)

// This doesn't:
  getAt(data.head, findMaxRangeDim(data))
```

The error is `could not find implicit value for parameter at: shapeless.ops.hlist.At.Aux[H,shapeless.Nat,BigDecimal]`.

I'm guessing that this happens because shapeless is looking for an implicit of the exact type of the result of `findMaxRangeDim(data)`, but this is known only at runtime. Is there any way of passing the right implicit and using the resulting **Nat** in another function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the approach by [Dmytro Mitin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51865949/5376123) but the compiler would simply complain that it couldn't find an implicit for the right type.

Then I asked in Shapeless' gitter channel, and realized that the compiler needs to know the specific type of the `Nat` at **compile time**. Because my code finds the right `Nat` at **runtime**, the compiler can't know beforehand which type to use.

The lesson learned being, `Nat`s are not analogous to indexes in typical Iterables.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify `findMaxRangeDim` so that it returns specific `N <: Nat` (e.g. add it as a type parameter) rather than just `Nat` (it's too rough).

Now `getAt(data.head, findMaxRangeDim(data))` doesn't work since there is no `At.Aux[H, Nat, BigDecimal]` (but there are `At.Aux[H, N, BigDecimal]` for specific `N <: Nat`).

Implicits are resolved at compile time, not at runtime.